# How to replace data in array

Tags: php

Current array structure

```
array:2 [
  "name" => "john"
  "data" => array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "id" => 191109
      "ref_num" => "INV9002"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "id" => 191110
      "ref_num" => ""
    ]
  ]
```

I'm trying to copy `id` to `ref_num` if `ref_num` is null. So far I did try like

Code

```
$izero = //that data structure above

foreach($izero['data'] as $key => $value) {
        if($value['ref_num'] === null) {
            $value['ref_num'] = $value['id'];
        }
        $izero['data'] = $value;
    }

$echo $izero
```

The result in `izero` missed the second array. It only keep the first array. Example if my `data` got 50 arrays, now it become the only one with first array.

The expected result should be like

```
array:2 [
  "name" => "john"
  "data" => array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "id" => 191109
      "ref_num" => "INV9002"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "id" => 191110
      "ref_num" => "191110"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers show how to fix this using a reference variable. If you want to assign to the array, you need to index it with `$key`:

```
foreach($izero['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value['ref_num'] === null) {
        $value['ref_num'] = $value['id'];
    }
    $izero['data'][$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `$izero['data']` each time.  Just reference `&` the value and then you can change it:

```
foreach($izero['data'] as &$value) {
        if($value['ref_num'] === null) {
            $value['ref_num'] = $value['id'];
        }
}
```

Or modify it by key:

```
foreach($izero['data'] as $key => $value) {
        if($value['ref_num'] === null) {
            $izero['data'][$key]['ref_num'] = $value['id'];
        }
}
```

Also, you don't show the actual value of the data and empty string `""` is NOT `===` to `null`.  You may want `empty` that checks for `""`, `0`, `null` and `false`:

```
        if(empty($value['ref_num'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tweaks to the code, if you change the `foreach` to use `&$value`, then you can update the value in place and not have to reassign the value at the end of the loop.

Also you have `($value['ref_num'] === null)`, as your checking for it to be null (in both value and type) and your array seems to have `""`.  So you should change the test...

```
foreach($izero['data'] as $key => &$value) {
    if(empty($value['ref_num'])) {
        $value['ref_num'] = $value['id'];
    }
}
```